# Azure Policy Tag with predefined values

Tags: azure, azure-resource-manager, azure-policy

I struggling currently at some point with Azure Policy. I want to enforce
a specific Tag and its value. (Sounds standard)
But I want to allow one value from a predefined set which
during creation is needed. For e.g.

Environment: (Any of these predefined values are allowed)

- Dev
- Test
- Prod
- PreProd

I created an Initiative with some other policies and when I assign this Initiative.

It will enforce only the chosen value but all other values are not allowed.

```
  "properties": {
    "displayName": "Tag3",
    "policyType": "Custom",
    "mode": "All",
    "metadata": {
    },
    "parameters": {
      "tags": {
        "type": "Array",
        "metadata": {
          "displayName": "Environment",
          "description": "The list of Environments"
        },
        "allowedValues": [
          "Test",
          "Dev",
          "PreProd",
          "Prod"
        ],
        "defaultValue": [
          "Prod"
        ]
      }
    },
    "policyRule": {
      "if": {
        "not": {
          "field": "tags",
          "in": "[parameters('tags')]"
        }
      },
      "then": {
        "effect": "deny"
      }
    }
  }
```

Comment: There's a community policy to help enforce this, defined here: https://github.com/Azure/Community-Policy/tree/master/Policies/Tags/require-tag-and-value-from-set

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Can you pls try this?...

```json
"properties": {
    "displayName": "Tag3",
    "policyType": "Custom",
    "mode": "All",
    "metadata": {
    },
    "parameters": {
      "tags": {
        "type": "Array",
        "metadata": {
          "displayName": "Environment",
          "description": "The list of Environments"
        },
        "allowedValues": [
          "Test",
          "Dev",
          "PreProd",
          "Prod"
        ],
        "defaultValue": [
          "Prod"
        ]
      }
    },
    "policyRule": {
      "if": {
        "not": {"or": {
          {"field": "tags",
          "equals": "Test"},
          {"field": "tags",
          "equals": "Dev"},
          {"field": "tags",
          "equals": "PreProd"},
          {"field": "tags",
          "equals": "Prod"},
        }
       }
      },
      "then": {
        "effect": "deny"
      }
    }
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

Set `defaultValue` without `[]`. Like this one :`"defaultValue": "Prod"`.

For more details, you could refer to this [article](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-resource-manager/management/tag-resources#templates).

Comment: Thanks Joey, but I stillhave troubles when I applying this policy, only one value will be allowed and not all of the array. Any idea on that?

Comment: Did you confirm that `"type": "Array"` you set  is array. Once a policy definition is saved, the type property on a parameter can't be changed.

Comment: As type was string, only one value can be set when assigning the policy. If this policy is assigned, resources in scope are only allowed. So, if your type is array, the situation is odd.

Comment: @mercure_01, did this solution work for you?

Answer (score 0):

Option1: Remove the "defaultvalue" property and provide the list of the desired values when you assign the policy, as a ';' separated list:

```
Test;Dev;PreProd
```

Option2: Leave the "defaultvalue" as array, filled with all allowed values:

```
"defaultvalue": [
          "Test",
          "Dev",
          "PreProd",
          "Prod"
        ]
```